# connection vs pool in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Прочитал кучу статей про подключение к postgres через connect и pool и вот что понял на текущий момент:

- connect лучше использовать для каждого query запроса и потом сразу закрывать (т.к. как я понял в среднем стоит лимит на 100 соединений, и если давать пользователю открывать постоянное соединение при открытии приложения, и закрывать его только при закрытии, то одновременно сможет подключаться только 100 человек) и то, что коннект открытый использует только 1 поток у процессора.

- pool представляет собой постоянное соединение с сервером, в котором мы также вызываем connect'ы, но можем использовать синхронно хоть все потоки, то есть, к примеру, делать 12 запросов одновременно.

Поправьте меня где я не прав, тк до конца не понял еще сам. Плюс объясните, что я упустил.

Comment: Серверу пофиг. Клиент работает с ним над одним запросом всегда через одно соединение. Всё, что ты описываешь - происходит на клиентской стороне.

Comment: А что за приложение такое, которое работает в большом количестве экземпляров и при этом требует прямого подключения к postgesql ?

Comment: @Mike нет приложения еще, просто сижу разбираюсь с graphql это меня унесло в сторону express js, express js унес меня в сторону как подключить бд и в куче примеров было либо client либо pool в качестве подключения, просто пытаюсь увидеть в чем разница

Comment: pool те же подключения, только все время открытые и используемые по мере необходимости. И большинство серверных web-приложений используют схему открытия одного соединения в момент прихода запроса от пользователя, выполнения через соединение нескольких запросов, необходимых для ответа клиенту и отключении. И уж точно заново открывать на каждый запрос не стоит. А pool позволит сэкономить на времени открытия соединений

Comment: но если у вас не обычное web-приложение, а что то другое, обслуживающее постоянную связь с пользователем, то возможно и модель работы с БД нужна другая

Comment: @Mike а не проще тогда просто использовать везде pool если он сокращает время, даже если количество пользователей небольшое?

Comment: ну и смысл стараться писать ответ если всё расписали в комментариях?

Comment: Использовать пул коннектов для приложения имеет смысл всегда при работе с postgresql. Внешний такой как pgbouncer или встроенный в приложение.

Comment: @Мелкий ответ имеет смысл писать, тк не все комменты читают))

Comment: @Мелкий есть ли смысл использовать pool.connect.query (и затем закрывать после каждого запроса) или можно просто бахать pool.query каждый раз?

Comment: Ни малейших идей даже про какой язык программирования вы спросили. Смотрите что за этими абстракциями происходит.